# How can I start the engine to solve my problem without Swing UI?

Tags: java, optaplanner, planning

Based on Optaplanner, I have already written the model, constraints, persistence, and xml configuration parts, just to start the engine part of the code.
I saw that the startup in the example is based on the Swing startup UI, but I don’t need the UI, so how do I start it? (Do not use the Swing part to display the interface)

Comment: do you have an analysis? if so, write the code to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

OptaPlanner documentation is very detailed and includes [an answer to this question](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#cloudBalancingMainMethod), too.